# DbGeography drawn circle is unwantedly egg shaped

Tags: sql-server, geometry, spatial, geo

I am using the DbGeography class to create a circle and draw it on the map but the product circle is not shaped correctly and instead is egg shaped.

```
string textPoint = String.Format("POINT ({0} {1})", longitude, latitude);
DbGeography point = DbGeography.PointFromText(textPoint, DbGeography.DefaultCoordinateSystemId); //4326 = [WGS84]
double earthsRadius = 3437.670013352;
radius = radius / earthsRadius;
DbGeography targetCircle = point.Buffer(earthsRadius);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The GEOGRAPHY data type is a geometry drawn on the surface of a sphere.  By drawing this on a plane the shape will be distorted.  This is what is known as a projection.  I am guessing you are probably using a mercator projection.  A mercator projection will take lat/long and draw them in a grid even though they are polar coordinates, not Cartesian.

Imagine peeling an orange.  When you are done, the orange peel is not a square and it does not lie perfectly flat.  To do this you would have to stretch it.  In the case of the mercator projection, you are stretching the top and bottom to the left and right while not touching the middle.  This makes a circle appear like an oval.

Comment: @Xerxes, Well this isn't really something to remedy, it is desirable, all points along the oval drawn are the same distance from the center.  You could maybe switch to a different projection which would potentially display the results less distorted, but that has its own issues and caveats to consider.

Comment: There's a whole wikipedia article on projections and some of the pros and cons of each. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection It looks like you're looking for a projection that is conformal. But as @hcaelxxam mentioned, everything you gain comes with a trade-off.